# Scrolling in UIView using IQKeyboardManager but without using UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield, iqkeyboardmanager

I am stuck in a screen where?

- I have two `UITextField`s at top and one `UIButton` at bottom.
- I have used `IQKeyboardManager` library so it is possible to scroll the entire page (till the bottom button) with keyboard present on the screen with the help of IQKeyboardManager and without use of UIScrollView.
- Though I have set layout constraint of IQKeyboardManager which is IQLayoutGuideConstraint to my bottom constraint but it is not working for me.
  `self.IQLayoutGuideConstraint = self.bottomLayoutConstraint`

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what else prob with using uiscrollview towards achieving this ..

Comment: @vaibhav: I don't have any problem with using UIScrollView but I simply don't want to use UIScrollView. So is full page scrolling  possible with IQKeyboardManager or not?

Comment: i dont have any experience with IQKeyboardManager but i have a perfect solution of your prob but with using scrollview now it depends on you whether i should tell or not.

Comment: Yo don't have to set constraints to use IQKeyboardManager, check here in the main page https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager. If you add it to your AppDelegate.swift it will work fine

Comment: @RodrigodeSantiago: I do not have any issue in using the IQKeyboardManager. I already added it to my AppDelegate.swift file and it is already working fine. Only I've the issue with its scrolling. Currently I'm not able to scroll the full page if keyboard is opened and without use of UIScrollView.

Comment: @RahulBansal Have you found any solution? I have same issue.

Comment: @Jasmit No, not yet :(